# How to change selected item in dropdown via clicking on an image (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I am using magento, but am far from jquery/javascript

I have a list of images that i want to be able to click and change the corresponding dropdown list selection.

I can have it set up so that select name/value or option value can be attached to each image that corresponds either using class or id.  So i just need the basic jquery to input

thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

Say the id of the image is the value of the dropdown item.

```
$('img').click(function() { 
    $('#dropdown').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/ecscY/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is definitely what I need it just doesn't work for some reason.  I removed all other jquery from page and tried to troubleshoot.  I also replaced the img with a class but it is a no go... i dont think it should matter but the img are in a li under seperate div than the select box